# How to append a string in aspx markup for accessing resource file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the code,

```
<asp:Label ID="_lblId" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resources1, prefix_lblId %>" >
```

Above code perfectly fine. But I want to pass keyword 'prefix' run-time by fetching it either from config or cache. '_lblId' will be passed as it is but keyword 'prefix' should be decided run-time.

Comment: Where are you going to pass that *prefix* in? Is that a global app wide setting? Something in the current session? per thread? `Resources1`  is a class with a property called `prefix_lblid`. Do you expect to have extra properties on that `Resources1`  class? Can't you (ab)use a language resource file for each prefix you want to plan for? (so each prefix will have its own language and then you only need to set the culture on the current thread and provide language resource files for each *prefix*)

Comment: You could declare a variable in the code behind class and use it in the aspx file.

Comment: @Christos It'd not work If I don't do label.Databind() in code behind

Comment: @rene No. I'm not using it for the purpose of localization. You can think of keyword _prefix_ as a State name of US for which application is running. I'd need to change text based on state configured in web.config

Comment: There are 52 states or so IIRC, there are > 52 cultures available. Use en-US as the fallback, assign each culture to a state( nl-NL -> WA; nl-BE -> FL, pt-BR -> CA; etc)

Comment: @rene I need to do it just for 3-4 states

Comment: Even if I follow your way, In that case, how'd I pass culture based on web.config or from cache to above code?

Comment: You can set the default culture in the web.config  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100) or per page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: Not helpful!!!!

Comment: What I basically need to do is replace response of <%$ AppSettings: Key1 %> with _prefix_. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: No, you can't. Those pages get compiled and AppSettings and Resources are special markers that thigh into known classes. Maybe you can override the Resources1 class with your own implementation but I doubt if you can then still use the Resources as you do now.